# Multiple Input and sending results to text

Tags: python, input, io

Please do not give the answer only.  I am new and this is my way of learning.  If you could take the extra time to explain the why or how I'd appreciate it.

I need to get multiple inputs I want the user to enter: ID, amount, tip amount.  Multiple instances of amount and tip.  Then port to text file
similar to this format:  Date, Employee ID, amount, Total sum of amount, tip amount, total sum of tip.

```
## Program gets the date, Employee ID, and amounts.  
## It then places them into a text file which can be ported to excel.

## Get Date


## Get Employee I.D.
empnum = raw_input('Please enter Employee Number\n')

## Gets the amounts.
num1 = raw_input('Please enter Ticket amount.\n')
num2 = raw_input('Please enter tip amount.\n')

## Sum of the amounts.
sum = float(num1) + float(num2)

## Information to be ported to text file.
## Date, Employee ID, amount, Total sum of amount, tip amount, total sum of tip
print'Employee ' + empnum + ' total is' 
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read input in required data type.

```
empnum = raw_input('Please enter Employee Number\n')
num1 = float(raw_input('Please enter Ticket amount.\n'))
num2 = float(raw_input('Please enter tip amount.\n'))
```

Now what you need to do is you have to open a file handler using `open` function in write mode .

```
fle =open("C:\Python27\projects\infile.txt",'w')
```

Do your calculations

```
sum = num1 + num2
```

And instead of printing you need write it to the file using `write` function

```
fle.write('Employee ' + empnum + ' total is ' + str(sum))
```

Then close file

```
fle.close()
```

Comment: Thank You.  I understand better and can implement your solution.  Will this write over that file each time this is ran and if so will 

with open("test.txt", "a") as infile:
    infile.write("appended text")            work to fix